# Facebook Notifications PHP

Tags: php, facebook, notifications

How can i make an app sent notification to the facebook?
i have tried many things on the internet and it didn't worked

this is the last thing i have tried, can some one help me?

```
    <?php
require_once "facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php";

$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/{user-id}/notifications',
    array (
        'href' => '/testurl?param1=value1',
        'template' => 'This is a test message',
    )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
?>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs and find what you want to do

Comment: debug the response and use try/catch